# Enable Highcharts Exporting On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm looking to programmatically *enable* exporting of all charts on a page.

Here's my current code:

```
$('.js-chart-export').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    charts = $('.chart').highcharts();
    charts.options.exporting.enabled = true;
});
```

`.js-chart-export` is a link that I'd like to be able to click to add the exporting button to all the charts. Each chart container has a class of `.chart`.

**What Else I've Tried**

There are a number of document ready's that have the original highchart calls. Experimenting with one, I called a chart such that the object was global (confirmed via console) and tried calling:

```
specific_chart.options.exporting.enabled = true;
```

Within that chart's object, the values changed but the button wasn't added to the chart. Next, I tried calling the `redraw()` function but that approach failed as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuantely you cannot dynamically do this, you need to destroy and create new chart.